# DocuSign integration via redirects

Tags: docusignapi

TL:DR - Is there a way to create an envelope via redirects between my app and DocuSign instead of using the REST API?

I want to create an integration between my app and DocuSign in the following way:

1. The user in my app uploads a document and click on a button called "Send with DocuSign".
2. The user get redirect to his DocuSign account to prepare the envelope (assuming he already authenticated).
3. In the DocuSign page the document is pre-populate and the user can add tabs and recipients to the envelope.
4. The user clicks on "Send" in DocuSign, the envelope sent to the recipients and the the user get redirect back to my app with some indication regarding the envelope status.

Is is possible?

I tried looking in DocuSign docs but didnt find any confirmation for the existence of the workflow I described even though I saw some app doing the exact same thing.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this and this exact scenario is not only documented but we show how to do it in eight languages.

[How to send an envelope from your app (Embedded Sending)](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/embedded-sending/)

Note thought that you do need to use the eSignature REST API to do this, I'm not aware of a way to do this without using the API. Perhaps something like Microsoft PowerApps (or Logic Apps) has this capability, but you'll still be using the REST API behind the scenes.

I strongly suggest you try to [download a quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) with the code of your choice and select the "Embedded Sending" code example to show you how it works.

Here is [some C# code](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/eSignature/Examples/EmbeddedSending.cs) (since you dind't say what coding lang):

```
    public static string SendEnvelopeUsingEmbeddedSending(string signerEmail, string signerName, string ccEmail, string ccName, string docDocx, string docPdf, string accessToken, string basePath, string accountId, string startingView, string returnUrl)
    {
        var docuSignClient = new DocuSignClient(basePath);
        docuSignClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(docuSignClient);

        // Step 1. Make the envelope with "created" (draft) status
        EnvelopeDefinition env = MakeEnvelope(signerEmail, signerName, ccEmail, ccName, docDocx, docPdf, "created");
        EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, env);
        string envelopeId = results.EnvelopeId;

        // Step 2. create the sender view
        // Call the CreateSenderView API
        // Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
        ReturnUrlRequest viewRequest = new ReturnUrlRequest
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
        };
        ViewUrl result1 = envelopesApi.CreateSenderView(accountId, envelopeId, viewRequest);

        // Switch to Recipient and Documents view if requested by the user
        string redirectUrl = result1.Url;
        Console.WriteLine("startingView: " + startingView);
        if ("recipient".Equals(startingView))
        {
            redirectUrl = redirectUrl.Replace("send=1", "send=0");
        }

        return redirectUrl;
    }
```

Comment: I dont think Embedded Sending is what Im looking for - I dont want to let the signer sign in my app. 
I want to redirect the user from my app to his DocuSign account with a document he uploaded in my app. Once he done with asserting tabs and recipients he would send the envelope and my app gets an identifier of the envelope to check its status on demand.

Comment: You are confusing embedded signing and embedded sending

Comment: Please note these are very different things, used for deferent purposes.

Comment: As for your last point about "check its status on demand" I would advise against this. I would suggest using a webhook to get updates about status changes. You could have UI that allows end-users to check status, but you cannot poll for status changes.

Comment: Thanks i tried it and it exactly what I looked for!

Comment: I'm glad to be of assistance, let me know if you need anything else