# DocuSign integration with third party application

Tags: docusignapi

Im a software developer working in a company and wish to integrate my app with my customers DocuSign account. My main goal is to implement the Embedded Sending service, allowing my customers to send envelopes which populated with documents and recipients coming from my app.

I know I need to have some app set up in DocuSign account and grabbing it relevant credentials fields.

With that said, Im not sure who is exactly should be responsible for creating this app -
Is it my customer? So he would create an app in his DocuSign account and share with me the relevant credentials fields for this integration?
Or it should be me, by using some Partner account or something like this?

I tried to look over DocuSign docs but got lost there.

Answer (score 1):

> With that said, Im not sure who is exactly should be responsible for
> creating this app - Is it my customer?

Eden, this is an excellent questions, and I'm afraid you are correct to point our that the DocuSign documentation does not answer this particular question.

The reason is that the only real answer is "it depends" :)

Let me explain. First, there's the question of capability, who has the knowledge, expertise, time, and money to build an integration. Sometimes it's the end-customer, sometimes it's a software vendor like you.

Then, there's the question of app management. DocuSign does give you the tools to manage some aspects of the app on your customer's behalf, but for the most part - they have to manage it. Meaning, they have to give consent for [your app](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/build-integration/) (based on an Integration Key or IK - clientId) to make API calls.

This part, the [consent](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/) and auth - [is well documented.](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/)

Also, we have full documentation of the embedded sending scenario and it's done in 8 different coding langs, not sure which one you need, but I answered your other question on this matter - [DocuSign integration via redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77511047/docusign-integration-via-redirects/77511787?noredirect=1#comment136654862_77511787)

Comment: Ok so let me get it right - I’m as an ISV needs to have a DS developer account for developing the integration.  Once done developing I need to “go live” which means to have a production DS account? And after that I can make an authentication between my integration/app and my clients DS accounts? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yes, if you join the DocuSign Partner program you can get a special ISV production account for free which you use to manage the app only.

Comment: Do you recommend to join the partner program? Im seeking for just implementing the Embedded Sending for now. Is there any core features (integration wise) that I will miss by using a regular production account? Thanks a lot again

Comment: no, the account has nothing to do with features, it's just a holding account for your integration key (IK , what we call a clientID) it nothing to do with features. The features are all based on your customers' account(s). They are the ones that will be using your integration, right?

Comment: Yes, my clients are the ones who will use my integration.

Comment: So, no problem, doesn't matter what account you use. First, make sure you can run your integration correctly in the developer account, then if you have an issue with go-live, you can ask us again...